# Recovering Functions and Stored Procedures from DATA folder on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i reinstalled my computer, but i just copied the `Data` folder from `mysql`, the problem is, my stored procedures and functions aren't there but the triggers are inside my databases.

What im doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the stored procedures are in the mysql/data/mysql/ folder. files are: proc.myi and proc.myd

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is seen this like me, you need to replace the 3 'proc' files, .myi .myd .frm in the mysql/mysql folder